# strange JVM vs .NET CLR performance difference (Short Lived objects + virtual calls)

Tags: java, .net, garbage-collection, jvm, clr

I'm testing the performance of crating+calling+abandoning large masses of short lived objects with virtual methods.

### Here is my C# code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace BoxingTest
{
    public abstract class BoxedVal
    {
        public abstract BoxedVal Add(BoxedVal other);
        public abstract bool LessThan(BoxedVal other);
        public abstract bool GreaterThan(BoxedVal other);
    }

    public class BoxedInt : BoxedVal
    {
        public int Value;

        public BoxedInt(int value)
        {
            Value = value;
        }

        public override BoxedVal Add(BoxedVal other)
        {
            BoxedInt i = other as BoxedInt;
            return new BoxedInt(Value + i.Value);
        }

        public override bool LessThan(BoxedVal other)
        {
            BoxedInt i = other as BoxedInt;
            return Value < i.Value;
        }

        public override bool GreaterThan(BoxedVal other)
        {
            BoxedInt i = other as BoxedInt;
            return Value > i.Value;
        }
    }

    class Program
    {
        private static int Fib(int nn)
        {
            BoxedVal one = new BoxedInt(1);

            BoxedVal a = one;
            BoxedVal b = one;

            BoxedVal n = new BoxedInt(nn);

            BoxedVal thousand = new BoxedInt(1000);

            for (BoxedVal i = new BoxedInt(2); i.LessThan(n); i = i.Add(one))
            {
                BoxedVal c = a.Add(b);
                a = b;
                b = c;

                if (b.GreaterThan(thousand))
                {
                    a = one;
                    b = one;
                }
            }
            return (b as BoxedInt).Value;
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int times = 5;
            int n = 20000000;

            int total = 0;

            for (int i = 0; i < times; i++)
            {
                var start = DateTime.Now;
                int val = Fib(n);

                int dt = (DateTime.Now - start).Milliseconds;
                total += dt;
                Console.WriteLine(val);
                Console.WriteLine("Elapsed: {0} ms", dt);
            }

            Console.WriteLine("Average: {0} ms", total / times);

            Console.ReadLine();

        }
    }
}
```

### And the same code in Java:

```
package boxingtest;

abstract class BoxedVal
{
    public abstract BoxedVal Add(BoxedVal other);
    public abstract boolean LessThan(BoxedVal other);
    public abstract boolean GreaterThan(BoxedVal other);
}


class BoxedInt extends BoxedVal
{
    public int Value;


    public BoxedInt(int value)
    {
        Value = value;
    }

    @Override
    public BoxedVal Add(BoxedVal other)
    {
        BoxedInt i = (BoxedInt)other;
        return new BoxedInt(Value + i.Value);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean LessThan(BoxedVal other)
    {
        BoxedInt i = (BoxedInt)other;
        return Value < i.Value;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean GreaterThan(BoxedVal other)
    {
        BoxedInt i = (BoxedInt)other;
        return Value > i.Value;
    }
}

public class BoxingTest {

    private static int Fib(int nn)
    {
        BoxedVal one = new BoxedInt(1);

        BoxedVal a = one;
        BoxedVal b = one;

        BoxedVal n = new BoxedInt(nn);

        BoxedVal thousand = new BoxedInt(1000);

        for (BoxedVal i = new BoxedInt(2); i.LessThan(n); i = i.Add(one))
        {
            BoxedVal c = a.Add(b);
            a = b;
            b = c;

            if (b.GreaterThan(thousand))
            {
                a = one;
                b = one;
            }
        }
        return ((BoxedInt)b).Value;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int times = 5;
        int n = 20000000;

        long total = 0;


        for (int i = 0; i<times;i++){
            long start = System.currentTimeMillis();

            int val = Fib(n);
            long dt = System.currentTimeMillis() - start;
            total+= dt;
            System.out.println(val);
            System.out.println("Elapsed: "+dt+" ms");
        }

        System.out.println("Average: "+(total/times)+" ms");

    }

}
```

### Results

I'm experiencing, that the Java (1.7) version is about **2 times** faster on my Windows machine than the .NET (4.5) one. Considering that both GC is generational and strongly optimized, I think it's a large difference, and I can't find anything on the net that explains it.

I want my .NET code to perform as fast at this scenario as Java does. Can I do this?
Has anybody an idea? Is there any article/blog post that helps me?

Comment: Is the .net code built as Release (not Debug) profile? Use dotTrace to trace the slowness, perhaps it's the Console printing not the objects. http://www.jetbrains.com/profiler/

Comment: There is no printing inside the measured code. And yes, tested it in release configuration. I profiled it with visual studio, and found nothing reasonable.

Please check/execute the code before downvoting.

Answer (score 3):

In my environment, Java 1.8.0.25 is about three times faster than .NET 4.5.1 (x64 both).
You get closer changing "as" expression to standard conversion. like

```
BoxedInt i = other as BoxedInt;
```

to

```
BoxedInt i = (BoxedInt)other;
```

And adding some constructions like

```
int Value;
int[] Dummy;

public BoxedInt(int value)
{
    Value = value;
    Dummy = new int[10];
}
```

to both made Java 8 times slower than .NET
This kind of micro-benchmarking shows interesting results, but is not practicable in many aspects.

Answer (score 1):

In this case, using the Server GC no changes because only one thread is running. The value types are also bad choice.
Value types make about 40% slower than the original because of too many BoxedInt constructions in BoxedInt.Add().

In this case, only difference between Java and .NET is a cost of the object construction.
If you use "only one integer" as a class and spend the most of time on it, use Java.

But this is only micro benchmark. As described before, adding only one reference of integer array makes Java slower.

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to approach this situation. Without changing code, enabling the "server" garbage collector should close that gap a bit:

[<gcServer> Element](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229357.aspx)

Another approach is carefully using value types instead of reference types in the C# code to avoid allocation altogether, even though you are working with many "instances" of the values. This isn't always the right approach, but for certain types of problems (especially the case you've shown above), value types can lead to the .NET code performing *many* times faster than equivalent Java code.